# Custom_module data not getting in $fieldset->addType('mycustomfield'). Magento2

Tags: magento2, adminform

Hi I need to get my custom module form data in getElementHtml().
Here is my form code:

```
$fieldset->addType(
        'mycustomfield',
        'MY\CustomModule\Block\Adminhtml\CustomModule\Renderer\Image'
    );  

    $fieldset->addField(
        'customdiv',
        'mycustomfield',
        [
            'name'  => 'customdiv',
            'label' => __('Custom Div'),
            'title' => __('Custom Div'),

        ]
    );
```

And below are my Image.php

```
<?php
namespace MY\CustomModule\Block\Adminhtml\CustomModule\Renderer;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;

class Image extends \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement
{


public function getElementHtml()
{

    $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('custommodule_id');
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

    $model = $objectManager->create('MY\CustomModule\Model\CustomModule');
    $model->load($id);

    return $model;
}
}
```

Did not get ID here. Even not able to create Objectmanage.
If I return just normal string it's only working like.

```
return 'Test';
```

It's working but not getting any data.
Can anyone see to get custom_module ID.

If I return $id OR $model then I get below error:

```
Item Information Changes have been made to this section that have not been saved. This tab contains invalid data. Please resolve this before saving.
```

Comment: Hi ravi, i have checked your requirement and you can try to get data from form registry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
$custommodule = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('custommodule');
$custommodule->getId();
```

Answer (score 0):

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
$custommodule = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('custommodule');
$custommodule->getId();

Comment: The use of `$objectManager` directly is not recommended.